# Whats wrong with the Elastic Search PHP search query?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've been trying to get the following JSON working in PHP Arrays but I don't seem to get any hits.

The JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "search"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "body",
    "title",
    "postDate",
    "user",
    "name"
  ],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": {
    "_score": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}
```

And the PHP I managed to create is like this:

```
$docs = $client->search([
    'index' => 'blog',
    'type' => 'posts',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'query_string' => [
                        'query' => $search_query
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'fields' => [
            'body',
            'title',
            'postDate',
            'user',
            'name'
        ],
        'from' => 0,
        'size' => 50,
        'sort' => [
            '_score' => [
                'order' => 'asc'
            ]
        ]
    ]

]);
```

It returns an response but no hits, even though it should (and it does in case of the JSON request)

What is going on here?

Comment: Can you show the URL you're using when sending the JSON query?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.. The post type wasn't required at all... I somehow thought it was. I used a tool called ElasticHQ to generate the JSON and i didn't realize it wasnt using Posts as a type.

Answer (score 0):

The post type wasn't required at all... I somehow thought it was. I used a tool called ElasticHQ to generate the JSON and i didn't realize it wasnt using Posts as a type.

Changed it to

```
$docs = $client->search([
    'index' => 'blog',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'query_string' => [
                        'query' => $search_query
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'fields' => [
            'body',
            'title',
            'postDate',
            'user',
            'name'
        ],
        'from' => 0,
        'size' => 50,
        'sort' => [
            '_score' => [
                'order' => 'asc'
            ]
        ]
    ]

]);
```

Comment: Almost, tomorrow I can :)